# Is there a Free Photoshop plugin/software which auto removes backgrounds?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-manipulation

I'm looking for a background removal plug-in or software that automates or at least eases the process of removing backgrounds from pictures / digital photos.

I have seen a few like [Mask Pro 4](http://www.ononesoftware.com/detail.php?prodLine_id=4), [Snap](http://www.digitalfilmtools.com/snap/) and [BackGround Remover](http://www.imageskill.com/backgroundremover/backgroundremover.html) all these are  paid software.

I would like to know if there are any free solutions available before I invest in any of the above plug-ins / software.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked through a lot of sites and have finally decided to purchase Back Ground Remover, it seems to suit my needs the best. Too bad there aren't any free utilities, plugin's or software's to do the same

Comment: You should have added this as a comment. Don't post something that's not an answer as one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just checking that you know about the Magic Eraser and Background Eraser built-in tools?

Comment: yes i do know of those, but i want a more automated way of doing so coz i have to do so in bulk.. and ideally with the least work on my end

Comment: Background Eraser sounds interesting...